# Wordpress Fatal error after update 4.0?

Tags: wordpress

I have this wordpress: www.verticalvideo.pt

And yesterday, I updated all the plugins, and then updated core to 4.0 (I checked if plugins could handle 4.0 before).

Everything seemed to went fine, even added some 'Posts'.

Today, the site gives me this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_category_id() in /home/vertical/public_html/wp/wp-content/themes/VideoTheme/VideoThemeRes/index.php on line 6
```

Is this because of wordpress update? Did the function 'get_category_id()' changed name or what?? Please help meeeee

PS: I ran UpdraftPlus Backup, but it's failing in restore backups -_-

Comment: You speak portuguese? If no, post here: http://stackoverflow.com/ , se sim, faça sua pergunta em portugês

Comment: Essa pergunta não pertence ao site porque não está em Português. Poderá traduzi-la. ~~ This question is off-topic because it's not written in Portuguese. It may be translated.

Comment: Ok..... ninguem no stackoverflowPT sabe ingles?... irei traduzir :o

Comment: @jbarradas não é uma questão de sabermos ou não, mas o fato do stack overflow pt ser em português. Não faz sentido termos perguntas em inglês em uma Exchange criada para termos a perguntas em português.